# Exception in Scope Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to follow this tutorial [Repository pattern without ORM](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/real-world-refactoring-dependency-injecting-a-non-orm-repository-for-aspnet-core-GU#comment-4967117474) that looks promising and did the exact thing as in the tutorial. My plan is simple, just to retrieve data from the database:

**Model**:

```
public class TeamDetails
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}

public class DataConnection
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }
}
```

**Ado Repository**:

```
public abstract class AdoRepository<T> where T : class
{
    
    private static SqlConnection _connection;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DemoApp;Trusted_Connection=True";

    public AdoRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public virtual T PopulateRecord(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    protected List<T> GetRecords(SqlCommand command)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        command.Connection = _connection;
        _connection.Open();
        try
        {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    list.Add(PopulateRecord(reader));
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
        return list;
    }

    protected T GetRecord(SqlCommand command)
    {
        T record = null;
        command.Connection = _connection;
        _connection.Open();
        try
        {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    record = PopulateRecord(reader);
                    break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
        return record;
    }
    
    protected IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProc(SqlCommand command)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        command.Connection = _connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _connection.Open();
        try
        {
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var record = PopulateRecord(reader);
                    if (record != null) list.Add(record);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Always call Close when done reading.
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Interface**:

```
public interface ITeam
{
    List<TeamDetails> GetAllTeams();
}
```

Implementing the team repository:

```
public class TeamRepository : AdoRepository<TeamDetails>, ITeam
{
    public TeamRepository(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public List<TeamDetails> GetAllTeams()
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from Team"))
        {
            return GetRecords(command);
        }
    }

    public override TeamDetails PopulateRecord(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        return new TeamDetails
        {
            TeamId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(0)),
            TeamName = reader.GetString(1)
        };
    }
}
```

A service interface:

```
public interface ITeamRepoService
{
    List<TeamDetails> GetAllTeams();
}
```

Implementing the service:

```
public class ITeamService : ITeamRepoService
{
    private readonly ITeam _repository;

    public ITeamService(IOptions<DataConnection> options)
    {
        var connection = options.Value;
        _repository = new TeamRepository(connection.DefaultConnection);
    }

    public List<TeamDetails> GetAllTeams()
    {
        return _repository.GetAllTeams();
    }
}
```

Finally calling it in the controller as follows:

```
 private readonly ITeamService _service;
 private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

 public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, ITeamService service)
 {
    _logger = logger;
    _service = service;
 }

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamDetails>>> Index()
{
  var teams = _service.GetAllTeams();

  return Ok(teams);
}
```

The issue is when I run the code, it throws an exception from the **Startup.cs** file:

```
Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: TodoApi.Interface.ITeam Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: TodoApi.Repository.TeamRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'TodoApi.Repository.TeamRepository'.)
```

In the start up file, I did the following but didn't work out:

```
services.Configure<DataConnection>(Configuration.GetSection("AppDbConnection"));

services.AddTransient<ITeamRepoService, ITeamService>();
services.AddTransient<ITeam, TeamRepository>();
```

Any way to resolve it?

Comment: Your TeamRepository expects a string in the constructor and you haven't told DI how to construct the object, so it is trying to get a string from DI, which doesn't work. Either add a function to AddTransient that constructs the object or change it to use a configuration/options object instead of a string.

Comment: Could you share a sample that I can study?

Comment: Hi @user8512043 , any update?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @Rena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @juunas said, your TeamRepository expects a string(`connectionString`), change your code below:

```
services.AddTransient<ITeam, TeamRepository>(_ => new TeamRepository("connectionString here"));
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#disposal-of-services